# How do I ensure the Facebook channel.html javascript is cached in Django?

Tags: python, django, facebook, caching

I'm new to Django and am trying to build an app that uses the FB API.  In order not to have to log in every time I load a page in my app, Facebook suggests I use a channel file with the following for users of PHP:

```
<?php
  $cache_expire = 60*60*24*365;
  header("Pragma: public");
  header("Cache-Control: maxage=".$cache_expire);
  header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$cache_expire).' GMT');
?>

<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

I'm wondering how I can effect the same for my Django app.  I don't want to use any of the plethora of Django-/Python-Facebook integrations out there since they usually include too many needless features that muck with my backend or too few features of the kind I don't like.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set response headers on an HTTP response function.  So if you wanted to emulate that PHP code, you can do something like this in your view:

```
def channel(request):
    response = HttpResponse('<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>')
    response['Pragma'] = 'public'
    ...
    return response
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice @nathan-jhaveri, but still no dice. 
Here's what I did:
(1) Update urls.py with 
    url(r'^channel/', 'channel'),
(2) Update my FB Init JS to include 
    FB.init({
       ...
       channelUrl : 'channel/',
(3) Update views.py with your code plus
...
cache_expire = 60*60*24*365
response['Pragma'] = 'public'
response['Cache-Control'] = 'maxage='+cache_expire
response['Expires'] = time.strftime('D, d M Y H:i:s', time.gmtime(int(time.time())+cache_expire))+' GMT'
 return response

Any idea what may be out of place?  Otherwise, I suspect the FB.init should access this view

Comment: And one more thing - i included some modules in views.py: 
from email.Utils import formatdate AND 
import time